# Prompting user for 2 dates and generating table with 0-23 hours for date range

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I need to prompt the user for 2 dates, e.g.  1/1/2008 , 2/5/2008 , and generate a two column report with all 0-23 hours for each date in the range. The date being in the first column and the hour being in the second column.

1/1/2008   0

1/1/2008   1

1/1/2008   3

[...etc]

2/4/2008   23

Comment: So what's your question?! Where exactly are you stuck in?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an hours table with 24 rows containing values 0-23, then do a cross join (no links) with each date in the range entered.

Comment: While it sounds silly, that's actually a really clever idea. However, I think the OP is having issues with looping in general in SQL (Access anyways).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that by doing a simple join on two temporary tables

```
SELECT tmpdate.day,tmp hour.time
FROM tmphour, tmpdate
ORDER BY tmpdate.day, tmphour.time;
```

`tmphour` containing a list hours 0-23 and `tmpdate` containing a list of dates